# Invoke fuse esb automatically

Tags: java, fuseesb, jbossfuse

I need to write an automated script which will call fuse esb and then it should call osgi:install command to deploy a bundle.. what is the best possible way? Any input/pointers highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SSH or the Karaf client to execute a script that installs a bundle etc. See some details here: http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest-2.3.x/users-guide/remote-console.html